# How can I EBS volume expansion for private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently using EC2 for private subnet, but I'm facing a "No space left on device" error, so I found out that EBS size needs to be expanded.
However, I cannot connect directly from aws in private subnet.
How can I access ec2 on private subnet to expand EBS volume?

Comment: If you want to login to an Amazon EC2 instance in a private subnet, I would recommend using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html). Please note that it requires some permissions to be assigned to the instance and requires the Systems Manager to be installed on the instance (which comes standard with Amazon Linux).

Comment: Ideally you would never SSH into an EC2 instance. In this case, you would modify your automation to increase EBS volume sizes, deploy the changes, then remove the failing instance from its Auto Scaling group, to be replaced by another with a larger EBS volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Modify volume` command in the Amazon EC2 management console to increase the size of the Amazon EBS volume.

Then, **Reboot** the instance and the root volume will be automatically resized to fill the new space.

None of this requires that you login to the instance.

See: [Request modifications to your EBS volumes - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply!
But how can I enter "Amazon EC2 management console"??

Comment: The Amazon EC2 management console is the website that you use to launch an Amazon EC2 instance.